# HAProxy multiple backends TCP/HTTP mode works only for one backend

Tags: haproxy

```
listen mqtt-ssl
    bind *:8883 ssl no-sslv3 crt /my.pem verify required ca-file /my/pem/all_cas.pem crl-file /my/pem/all_crls.pem
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log global
    maxconn 50000
    tcp-request inspect-delay 30s
    use_backend pki unless { req.payload(0,0),mqtt_is_valid }
    default_backend emqx_k8s_svc

backend pki
    mode http
    server pki.my.domain someIP:443 ssl verify none

backend emqx_k8s_svc
    mode tcp
    log global
    server emqx1 emqx-ee.emqx:1883 check inter 30s downinter 30s fall 1 rise 1
```

Given the above haproxy.cfg snippet, I confirm the following issue:

When I do a curl/wget on the listening address, the request is normally forwarded to the `backend pki` , as it should. But, at the same time, when attempting a connection to the `backend emqx_k8s_svc` the Mosquitto client stays blocked at "sending CONNECT" and no connection is established.

How can I have the condition that if the request payload is of type MQTT then forward it to the `default_backend`, and if the connection is NOT MQTT (say, an http client) forward it to  the `backend pki` .

I have also tried the following , without resolve:

```
tcp-request inspect-delay 30s
use_backend pki if !{ req.payload(0,0),mqtt_is_valid }
use_backend emqx_k8s_svc if { req.payload(0,0),mqtt_is_valid }
default_backend emqx_k8s_svc
------------------------------
tcp-request inspect-delay 10s
use_backend pki if { ssl_fc }
use_backend emqx_k8s_svc if { req.payload(0,0),mqtt_is_valid }
default_backend emqx_k8s_svc
```

NOTE: it is all running in a Kubernetes environment, except for the `backend pki` which is elsewhere (but accessible) - HAProxy version: 2.5

Comment: and your version of `haproxy` is?

Comment: @AlexD  sorry, i just edited the post, it's 2.5